# Limited Release or Select Theaters

Tags: distribution

When a movie is getting a "limited release" or will be released "only in select theaters", how can I most quickly find the nearest theater that will be showing it?

Related but separate question: How can I get the list of theaters for a limited release movie?

Example: Kingsglaive: Final Fantasy XV will be a limited release. So far my search hasn't revealed if it'll be releasing anywhere near me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because locating content is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the movie's official site will list the dates and theaters.  [Kingsglaive](http://www.kingsglaivefinalfantasyxv-movie.com/site/) is no exception; there's a button to "Find a Theater" at the bottom of the site.